# Computation of brightness of the twilight sky

Tags: visible-light

I would like to make the computations of twilight sky in mag/arcsec2 based on the solar depression and brightness.

So far I found a nice article about it:

https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1966SvA.....9..840D/0000842.000.html

where the following formulas can be found:

[image]

In the first one, I don't understand the azimuth calculation from solar vertical.

The second one doesn't include the solar apparent magnitude. Is it included in any factor maybe?